# JQuery Validation for Array of Input Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

I need to validate an array of input text elements (mileage): For example:

```
<tbody>
  <c:forEach items="${list}" var="item">
        <tr> 
             <!--some other columns---> 
             <td align="left"><input type="text" name="mileage" value="" /></td>
        </tr>
   </c:forEach>                       
</tbody>
```

The script for validation is as below -

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#form1").validate({
            rules: {
                mileage: {
                    required: true

                         }
                },            
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                form.submit();
            }

        });       
    });
```

Now the problem is that the .validate.js only validates the first element of mileage. What can I do? How can I make the plugin validate all of the inputs text ?

I hope you can help me out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In jquery.validate.js, we can find a function named checkForm, we have to modify it as below:

```
checkForm: function() {
                this.prepareForm();
                for ( var i = 0, elements = (this.currentElements = this.elements()); elements[i]; i++ ) {
                    if (this.findByName( elements[i].name ).length != undefined && this.findByName( elements[i].name ).length > 1) {
                        for (var cnt = 0; cnt < this.findByName( elements[i].name ).length; cnt++) {
                            this.check( this.findByName( elements[i].name )[cnt] );
                        }
                        } else {
                    this.check( elements[i] );
                }
                }
            return this.valid();
    }
```

Comment: Excellent indeed. But I have found that this function does not take into count the "ignore" property. I have just refined the function in my answer. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Based on [eddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/530911/eddy) answer, this function takes into count also the `ignore` setting.

```
        checkForm: function() {
            this.prepareForm();
            for ( var i = 0, elements = (this.currentElements = this.elements()); elements[i]; i++ ) {
                var checkingElements = this.findByName( elements[i].name ).not(this.settings.ignore);
                if (checkingElements.length !== undefined && checkingElements.length > 1) {
                    for (var cnt = 0; cnt < checkingElements.length; cnt++) {
                        this.check( checkingElements[cnt] );
                    }
                } else {
                    this.check( elements[i] );
                }
            }
            return this.valid();
        },
```

Comment: I prefer not to manipulate plugin source code manually but instead include my custom hot fixed in a seperate .js file, which I then include on the page after jquery.validate.js. Is there a way this can be done with the checkForm-method in the extension?

Comment: I have forked the project on github and did a pull request, so hopefully you will find this update directly in a new version of jquery.validate.js

Answer (score 3):

You have to loop through in these cases, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form1").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });  
    $("#form1 input[name='mileage']").each(function() {
       $(this).rules("add", { required: true });
    });  
});
```

[`.rules()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules) only affects the first match, so you need a [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) on there to loop through and add any rules to all matches.

Comment: @Nick Craver.  Thank you I tried what you suggested, but it still doesn't work :(. Are you sure that's all I need to do?? :(

Comment: @eddy - yup that's all that's needed...are you getting any JavaScript errors in your console?

Comment: @Nick Craver-  No a single error. For some reason the plugin keeps validating only the first element  :(

Comment: @eddy - do you have a page I can look at? btw another way to go about it, if you just want `required` would be `<input type="text" name="mileage" class="required" />`

Comment: @nick hi nick, tell you what.. you're my fav in the entire SO community. I love the way you feel responsibility for the Community. I just wanted to say `you're my number One` (nothing Personal)

Comment: @Nick Craver- Finally I found how to make the plugin work properly :http://web-funda.blogspot.com/2009/05/jquery-validation-for-array-of-input.html . Now it work fine I just hope it doesn't cause me any problem in the future

Comment: @Nick. I just replaced the function named checkForm and  with  that ,I got fixed the problem :D

Comment: @eddy - you *can* do that, but the above should work...I'd give a jsfiddle example if they weren't having issues at the moment.  Modifying a non-broken plugin is *never* the right approach IMO.

Comment: @Nick. thank you , you've been really helpful, and I'd really appreciate if you can give that example

Comment: @eddy - I stand corrected, since 1.6 this no longer works...curious that the author chose to only support checkboxes and radiobuttons for shared `name` attributes, not sure what the thought process was there, since this *is* valid HTML.

Comment: @Nick-Could you please, give me a hand over here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528399/how-to-check-if-a-checkbox-in-a-checkbox-array-is-checked-with-jquery  :'(

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery validate 1.19.1 and modifying the jquery.validate.js file on line 465, replacing with this function should be fine.

```
checkForm: function() {
            this.prepareForm();
            for ( var i = 0, elements = (this.currentElements = this.elements()); elements[i]; i++ ) {
                var checkingElements = this.findByName( elements[i].name ).not(this.settings.ignore);
                if (checkingElements.length !== undefined && checkingElements.length > 1) {
                    for (var cnt = 0; cnt < checkingElements.length; cnt++) {
                        this.check( checkingElements[cnt] );
                    }
                } else {
                    this.check( elements[i] );
                }
            }
            return this.valid();
        },
```

I hope to be of help ;)