# jQuery validation with array of control (same names)

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I already read this thing on jQuery validation but still I'm stuck with this requiring control array in the form.

I have this code:

```
//already link the validation js script of course

<scrip>
    $(document).ready(function() {  
    $("#hh").validate();
    });
</script>

<form id="hh">
<input type="text" name="name[]" class="required" /><br />
<input type="text" name="name[]" class="required" /><br />
<input type="text" name="name[]" class="required" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="Submit" />
</form>
```

The problem is, the first row of control named 'name[]' is required the rest is nothing.
I already make update to `checkForm: function()` on `jquery.validate.js` as what the this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526229/jquery-validation-for-array-of-input-elements) says but its nothing...

Adding `class="required"` to every controls is working for me actually, but I'm stuck with this control array thing...

Can anybody please submit a step by step on how to solve this problem? A very simple lines on code that already working is a good help; Like modifying the code I posted above.

I'm sorry I'm already frustrated with this thing.

Comment: Have you tried removing `class="required"` from the other two input boxes?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
<form id="hh">
<input type="text" name="name[0]" class="required" /><br />
<input type="text" name="name[1]"  /><br />
<input type="text" name="name[2]"/><br />
<input type="submit" name="Submit" />
</form>
```

?

Comment: Thanks, but the name[0], etc. wont accept using my code on PHP post request.. I think the array of my code is out of bounds..

like this in codeigniter..
`code`
<?php
$name = $this->input->post('name');// there is no issue with this line

for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($name); $i++) {
echo $name[$i].'<br />';
}
`code`