# jQuery Validation Plugin with Input Arrays

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, expressionengine

I currently have a set of inputs that look like this:

```
<li class="required">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="cf_member_address[row_id_52][col_id_19]" value="">
</li>
<li class="required">
    <label>Surname</label>
    <input type="text" name="cf_member_address[row_id_52][col_id_20]" value="">
</li>
```

and I'm using jQuery validate to validate the form before it submits. I'm trying to add custom messages to each item but i've hit a problem because of the arrays ([row_id_52])

Also, depending on the form that loads, depends on what row ID shows ([row_id_52]) - But the Col ID stays the same.

How can I declare:

- An Array input field that has a dynamic number in it?

In my JS file? I'm currently doing it like this:

```
cf_member_first_name: "Please enter your First Name",
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Sorry Jason, I don't understand what you are trying to say. Is there a link so we can see the problem too?

Comment: Doesn't class="required" need to be on the actual <input> required? <input .... class="required" />? Also, if I am reading this correct, maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526229/jquery-validation-for-array-of-input-elements

Comment: @sisko I'm basically trying to get my cf_member_address[row_id_52][col_id_20] input field to have a custom error message. jQuery Validate plugin doesn't like that it's using an Array for the name of the field, so I need to figure a way around this.

Comment: @buildakicker I forgot to mention that the class="required" is being added dynamically. So when I set the class="required" on the <li> element, it adds it to the input fields as well, and adds an asterisks next to the label. It just saves me doing it on every input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jQuery validate will allow you to add validation rules using a selector other than the input name, so one way to avoid your issue of dynamic names is to assign a css id or class to each of your inputs and set up your validation rules per id or class. http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules

Comment: This sounds good, I think I may switch to adding an individual ID to each element then. Will give it a bash and let you know if it works...

Comment: @JasonMayo just letting you know about our proposal for an EE specific site here (if you already are supporting it, you need to link your account so your reputation counts towards it) http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/46387/expressionengine

Answer (score 3):

If your are on ExpressionEngine you can try '[Forms JS Validation](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/forms-js-validation)' for validate your forms using EE tags. Otherwise you can use the [Validation Library](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine) as an jQuery library, it`s works great with input arrays.

Comment: I tried this, but it got a bit too fiddly for what I needed. Lovely plugin, but wanted a bit more control over everything.